# is there anyway to increment exponentially in swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop, increment

I am trying to write a for loop, where I have to increment exponentially. I am using `stride` function but it won't work.
Here's c++ code, I am trying to write a swift version.

`for (int m = 1; m <= high - low; m = 2*m){}`

can you help me, to write this code in swift version?

Comment: C-style for-loops are no longer in Swift as of Swift 3 https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md

Answer (score 6):

A while-loop is probably the simplest solution, but here is an alternative:

```
for m in sequence(first: 1, next: { 2 * $0 }).prefix(while: { $0 <= high - low }) {
    print(m)
}
```

`sequence()` (lazily) generates the sequence 1, 2, 4, ...,   and `prefix(while:)` limits that sequence to the given range.

A slight advantage of this approach is that `m` is only declared inside the loop (so that it cannot be used later accidentally), and that is is a *constant* so that it cannot be inadvertently modified inside the loop.

Comment: honestly: the other answer is easier to read, but you got my vote for coolness ;-)

Comment: Side note: `.prefix` can be dropped, and condition moved inside of `next` callback. If condition fails, `next` returns `nil`, otherwise `2 * $0`. It can be done, but I'm not saying it should be done, just a remark.

Comment: @user28434: There is a small difference (which may or may not be relevant): If you move the condition into the next closure of the sequence function then the loop body is executed *at least once,* even if the condition is initially wrong.

Comment: This is also workable: `for m in (sequence(first: 1) {
       return  $0 <= (high-low) ?  $0 * 2 : nil
}).dropLast(){
print( m )
}`

Answer (score 3):

There is no `for` loop in Swift, but you can achieve the same result with basic `while` loop

```
var m = 1                // initializer
while m <= high - low {  // condition
    ...
    m *= 2               // iterator
}
```

Comment: what if have to go with for loop?

Comment: @HaaniDev there is no for loop in swift. But this while loop is replacement of it.

Comment: @HaaniDev why would you __have to__ use a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@MartinR answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55496226/6920962), only improvement is readability of the call:

```
// Helper function declaration
func forgen<T>(
    _ initial: T, // What we start with
    _ condition: @escaping (T) throws -> Bool, // What to check on each iteration
    _ change: @escaping (T) -> T?, // Change after each iteration
    _ iteration: (T) throws -> Void // Where actual work happens
    ) rethrows
{
    return try sequence(first: initial, next: change).prefix(while: condition).forEach(iteration)
}

// Usage:
forgen(1, { $0 <= high - low }, { 2 * $0 }) { m in
    print(m)
}
// Almost like in C/C++ code
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `for`:

```
let n = Int(log(Double(high - low))/log(2.0)) 
var m = 1
for p in 1...n {
    print("m =", m)
    ...
    m = m << 1
}
```

(Supposing that `high - low` is greater than 2)